# Calculate a total in a report/query

Tags: mysql

Have 3 tables that I have linked to together one filed is cable type and I would like to get a total by cable type, "bd.buss_cable"

```
select 
r.residence_id,

bd.buss_id,
bd.buss_description,
bd.sub_system,
bd.sub_mfg,
bd.sub_drop_id,
bd.buss_address,
bd.buss_cable,

bs.Drop_id,
bs.bus_order,
bs.next_drop,
bs.distance_next_drop,
bs.subsystem_code

from Residence as r
left join buss_drops as bd on
r.residence_id = bd.Residence_residence_id


left join bus_sequience as bs on
bd.buss_id = bs.bus_buss_id

where r.residence_id = 'Andora 9661'
#order by r.residence_id, bd.buss_cable, bd.buss_id, bs.bus_order
group by bd.buss_cable

;
```

Comment: Note that this is an inner join and the group by clause is never going to end well

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a count, then add

```
count(*)
```

to your column list, otherwise add

```
sum(column-to-be-totalled)
```

to the column list.

You are already grouping on the required column so I would have thought one of these would do the trick.

Apologies if I have misunderstood the problem.